# dependencies were not found when trying to import selected components from vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js

when trying to import selected modules from vuetify.js like so:

```
import Alerts               from 'vuetify/src/components/alerts';
import App                  from 'vuetify/src/components/app';
import Avatars              from 'vuetify/src/components/avatars';
```

webpack throws an error:

```
These dependencies were not found:
* ~util/helpers in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/avatars/index.js, ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/cards/index.js and 14 others
* ~directives in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/lists/VListTile.js, ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/menus/VMenu.js
* ~directives/click-outside in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/selects/VSelect.js
* ~directives/ripple in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/selection-controls/VCheckbox.js
* ~mixins/themeable in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/app/VApp.js, ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/cards/VCard.js and 12 others
...
To install them, you can run: npm install --save ~util/helpers ~directives ~directives/click-outside ~directives/ripple ...
```

it seems that vuetify.js uses the '~' alias for it's project.

How to fix this issue in my project and be able to use single components of third party project anyway?

I have already tried to set up the '~' alias to their source:

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {'~': NODE_MODULES + '/vuetify/src'},
    },
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding following config:

```
    resolve: {
        modules: ['./node_modules', './node_modules/vuetify/src'],
        alias: {
            '~': './app',
            '~components': 'components',
            '~directives': 'directives',
            '~mixins': 'mixins',
            '~stylus': 'stylus',
            '~util': 'util'
        },
    },
```